# Pine Script: Exit strategy X bars after opening strategy

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to close a strategy either after it crosses above the MA or after 50 bars, whichever comes first
I have been trying to look into and it seems "barstate.isconfirmed" or "barsince" function should be used. 
Currently I have the below, what do I need to add to include closing after 50 bars?

```
strategy.close("buy",when = close[0]>basis
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index` built-in variable to get the bar index of the open trade. Then compare it with the current bar index.

```
n = 50
open_idx = strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades-1)
diff_idx = bar_index - open_idx

if (diff_idx >= n)
    strategy.close("buy")
```

Comment: Thanks. I get the below error. I am using version 4, do I need to change version?
Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 34: Could not find function or function reference 'strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index'.

Comment: You should use version 5.

Answer (score 0):

For the 50 bars, use this with v5:

```
//Start counting after trade entry
barsSinceLastEntry() =>
    strategy.opentrades > 0 ? bar_index - strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index
(strategy.opentrades - 1) : na

// Setup for closing the long position after 50 bars. 
if barsSinceLastEntry() >= 50
    strategy.close("Long")


//Exit when greater than 50 bars after entering the trade
if barsSinceLastEntry() >= 50
    strategy.close("Long")
```